# Invoke function after div resize is complete?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a resizeable div like this:

```css
div{
  resize:both;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:10rem;
  width:10rem;
  border:solid 0.5rem black;
}
```

```html
<div id="item" ></div>
```

How do I invoke a function **after** it has completed resizing?

i.e. I don't want the function to continuously invoke while it's being resized,
rather I need it to invoke after the mouse has been lifted from the bottom right resizing icon [image]

Comment: A `ResizeObserver` combined with a debouncer?

Comment: @somethinghere I'm sorry I don't follow

Comment: @somethinghere  You might want to add a `mouseup` too, otherwise the debounce could fire while resizing.

Comment: This seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/8o4r5p6a/

Comment: @ChrisG i guess that does, but I was hoping there was a solution that doesn't involve having to check every time the div was being resized? https://jsfiddle.net/vu254qz8/

Comment: I have added an answer to clear up the `ResizeObserver` + `debouncer` thing. Also @Keith The `mouseup` doesn't actually guarantee a resize occurred, so you would still need a resize event.

Comment: @somethinghere  Yes, did you read my answer to OP on that point?

Comment: Okay, okay, might have read over that one liner saying there are other devices. Still, you can mouseup without resizing too ;)

Comment: @somethinghere  Yes, I know, but of course the x&y would be the same, ps. not saying the debounce is bad or anything (how I would do it), it's just the OP wanted to fire an event after resize not during, as your snippets shows events can still fire while still resizing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just check the `mouseup` event, and track the old v new size.

The only gotcha here is if there are other ways to resize the div other than using the mouse.

```js
const item = document.querySelector('#item');

function getSize() {
  return {
    w: item.offsetWidth,
    h: item.offsetHeight
  }
}

let old = getSize();

item.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  let n = getSize();
  if (old.w !== n.w && old.h !== n.h) {
    console.log('resized: ' + JSON.stringify(n));
    old = n;
  }
});
```

```css
#item {
  resize:both;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:10rem;
  width:10rem;
  border:solid 0.5rem black;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height:50px!important;
}
```

```html
<div id="item" ></div>
```

Comment: I had a feeling someone might post something like this, and although this solution might work it still does kind of repeat itself, especially if the inside of the div is being clicked multiple times  https://jsfiddle.net/vu254qz8/2/

Comment: @cakelover  Do you mean like some sort of `resized` event?, no I don't believe there is anything like that.  You could however create a custom event to do something like this, that basically used this technique in the background.  What problem are you trying to solve by preventing the repeating bit?, you placed the `console.log` outside the check, you of course would want that inside the check.  Then the only repeating bit is the check, that's practically a zero cost in performance if that's your aim.

Comment: I was hoping for a solution that included some event or function I perhaps missed but if that's not the case then I guess this answer is as good as any

Answer (score 1):

What I meant by combining a `ResizeObserver` and a `debouncer` is something like this:

```js
const observerDebouncers = new WeakMap;
const observer = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
    
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    
    // Clear the timeout we stored in our WeakMap if any
    clearTimeout( observerDebouncers.get( entry.target ) );
    // Set a new timeout to dispatch an event 200 ms after this resize
    // if this is followed by another resize, it will be cleared by the above.
    observerDebouncers.set( entry.target, setTimeout(() => {
      
      entry.target.dispatchEvent( new CustomEvent( 'resized' ) );
      
    }, 200) );
    
  })
  
});

const resizeable = document.querySelector( 'div' );

resizeable.addEventListener( 'resized', event => {
  
  console.log( 'resized' );
  
});

// Register the resize for this element
observer.observe( resizeable );
```

```css
#item {
  resize:both;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:10rem;
  width:10rem;
  border:solid 0.5rem black;
}
```

```html
<div id="item" ></div>
```

A little bit of a breakdown: `observerDebouncers` just contains a weakly mapped list from a target to the current timeout stored. It's weakly bound so if you ever remove the element, the timeout id is automatically lost. This means you never really have to worry about the memory consumption here becoming unwieldy.

The `observer` itself just creates a timeout for every resize event it receives. It also cancelled the previously stored timeout. This means that as long as there is continuous dragging, the timeout will get cancelled and the `resized` event delayed by 200 more milliseconds. If the resizing stops, the event will fire 200 milliseconds later. (Thats what's called a debouncer, its very common logic in JS to limit the amount of actual events being fired).

The last thing you then need to do is listen for the event and add the target to the observer and voila, a `resized` event.

This seems like a lot of boilerplate, but it's rather efficient. The only improvement you could make would be to register a single event handler for every target (again, weakly), which would prevent a new function being created every call. A little bit like this:

```js
const observerDebouncers = new WeakMap;
const observerHandlers = new WeakMap;
const observer = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
    
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    
    // This will only happen once, so only one method per target is ever created
    if( !observerHandlers.has( entry.target ) ){
      
      observerHandlers.set( entry.target, () => {
      
        entry.target.dispatchEvent( new CustomEvent( 'resized' ) );

      });
      
    }
    
    // Same as before, except we reuse the method
    clearTimeout( observerDebouncers.get( entry.target ) );
    observerDebouncers.set( entry.target, setTimeout( observerHandlers.get( entry.target ), 200 ) );
    
  })
  
});

const resizeable = document.querySelector( 'div' );

resizeable.addEventListener( 'resized', event => {
  
  console.log( 'resized' );
  
});

observer.observe( resizeable );
```

```css
#item {
  resize:both;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:10rem;
  width:10rem;
  border:solid 0.5rem black;
}
```

```html
<div id="item" ></div>
```